# 74141 BCD-to-decimal converter not working?

Tags: converter

[image]
I set port D are output and have hex value 0xca at BCD format. But LED is all HIGH.
I wonder why this converter not do its function??

Comment: Who taught you how to use a 74141? Because that's not how you use it.

Comment: I studied its datasheet by myself then used it. Could you show me my mistakes? Thanks

Comment: The outputs are 'open collector', so you need to connect the common side of your LEDs to Vcc and you will need current limiting resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use your 74141 is wrong. 
Please look at the added picture and look at the truth table in de data sheet for a good understanding of the system.

You have to set the input ports high to get only one output port active.
For instance ABCD (1000) high will activate the Q1 on the output.

[image]